A pawn moves along the vertices of a tetrahedron $ABCD$. Probability that the pawn will return to $A$ before reaching $B$. Solution verification.
A pawn moves along the vertices of a tetrahedron $ABCD$, in each move moving to one of the adjacent vertices (each possibility has a $\frac{1}{6}$ chance), or staying put (with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$). Assuming that the pawn is initially at vertex $A$, calculate the probability that the pawn will return to vertex $A$ before reaching vertex $B$.

I think that we can create an imaginary point A' that is the point where the pawn starts. Then by A we will mark the point A to which the pawn can return.
From that we have such equations:

$p_{A'} = \frac{1}{2} p_{A'} + \frac{1}{6} p_B + \frac{1}{6} p_C + \frac{1}{6} p_D$
$p_C = \frac{1}{6} p_{A} + \frac{1}{6} p_B + \frac{1}{2} p_C + \frac{1}{6} p_D$
$p_D = \frac{1}{6} p_{A} + \frac{1}{6} p_B + \frac{1}{6} p_C + \frac{1}{2} p_D$
$p_A =  1$
$p_B =  0$

From that system of equations we want to calculate $p_{A'}$, as we start from there. We have: $p_{A'} = \frac{1}{3}$.
Is that correct?
This question is similar to other two that I've asked:
A pawn moves between the vertices of a square ABCD. Expected number of the move in which the pawn first moves from point B to C. Solution verification
A pawn moves across the fields of the board. Calculate the expected value of the number of moves after which the pawn will visit all fields.

Staying put has no effect on the final result, so you might as well ignore it, and set the probability of moving to an adjacent vertex to $\frac13$.

Like the answer below, I solved it more intuitively, but I am very impressed by this formalization, including the insight of inventing a fifth label for the starting point.

That's sarcasm? I was just looking for a more methodic / replicable way of solving those types of markov-chain relations (by expressing them as an system of equations). I've got another one here that I'm having trouble figuring out. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4933539/a-pawn-moves-along-the-vertices-of-a-square-abcd-expected-number-of-the-move-in Maybe you could have a look at this one @DavidK

Oops, sorry, not sarcasm at all. I may have been a little too enthusiastic. It was just that it took me a moment to recognize exactly what you were doing.

@DavidK no hard feelings, I was just wondering if you tried to say that I managed to complicate such an easy problem by 'producing 5 variables' :D

@TonyK, thanks. I just saw your comment when you accused me of stealing your idea and downvoted my other question saying that it is the same (even though it is about counting steps over sqare and not calculating probabilities over tetrahedron and contains different points that I'm not sure about and therefore I ask - different imaginary label and idea of counting steps).

Side note: Given these probabilities, the question is equivalent to: Choose $\sigma$ from amongst the permutations of ${A, B, C, D}$ that do not begin with $A$. What is the probability that $A$ precedes $B$ in $\sigma$? That's probably easier to answer. However, change the transition probabilities and it's no longer to proceed in that fashion.

This is correct.  A simpler way to approach it is to say $p_C=p_D=\frac 12$ by symmetry.  When you leave C or D for A or B you have the same chance to go to either and be done.  Then when you leave A you have $\frac 13$ chance to go to B and be done and $\frac 23$ chance to go to $C$ or $D$, giving a $\frac 13$ chance of returning before going to $B$
