A pawn moves between the vertices of a square ABCD. Expected number of the move in which the pawn first moves from point B to C. Solution verification
A pawn moves between the vertices of a square $ABCD$, in each move moving to one of the adjacent vertices - the choice of each vertex is equally likely choices at different steps are independent. Initially, the pawn is located at point $A$. Let $X$ denote the number of the move in which the pawn first moves from point $B$ to $C$. Determine the expected value of $X$.

From that we have such equations ($C'$ is the imaginary $C$ that move from $B$ leads to and is the last move in the chain of moves):

$p_A = \frac{1}{2} p_B + \frac{1}{2} p_D + 1$
$p_B = \frac{1}{2} p_A + \frac{1}{2} p_{C'} + 1$
$p_C = \frac{1}{2} p_B + \frac{1}{2} p_D + 1$
$p_D = \frac{1}{2} p_C + \frac{1}{2} p_A + 1$
$p_{C'} = 0$

Solving those gives me an answer $p_A = 8$. Does it look correct? I'm not sure if it's enough to just add $1$ step in every equation to solve the original problem.
That question is similar to other two that I've asked
A pawn moves across the fields of the board. Calculate the expected value of the number of moves after which the pawn will visit all fields.
A pawn moves along the vertices of a tetrahedron $ABCD$. Probability that the pawn will return to $A$ before reaching $B$. Solution verification.

Why is $p_A=8$ "obviously wrong"?

Why don't you mention your previous very recent question ?

Ohhhh, I forgot that I'm calculating number of steps, not probability!

That actually might be right. Does it look right to you? @aschepler

You are right, I could link that, do I need to fix that or is it done by now (as it appears in "linked" section on the RHS)? @JeanMarie

As you like it...

Ok, changed that. English is not my first language, sorry.

I don't understand your definition of the "imaginary" $\ C'\ ,$ but you don't need it in any case. If you define $\ p_V $ to be the expected number of moves for the pawn to reach $\ C\ $ along the edge $\ BC\ $, given that it is currently at vertex $\ V\ ,$ then your equations for $\ p_A,p_C\ $ and $\ p_D\ $ are correct.  If the pawn is at vertex $\ B\ ,$ however, then there's a probability of $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ that the pawn will execute the target transition in just one move, and a probability of $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ that it will move to vertex $\ A\ .$ Your equation for $\ p_B\ $ should therefore be
$$
p_B=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{p_A+1}{2}\ ,
$$
and this is the same equation you get from your current system, after you substitute  $\ p_{C'}=0\ $ into your equation for $\ p_B\ .$
I get $\ p_A=8, p_B=5, p_C=8,p_D=9\ .$  By substituting these values into the equations you can confirm that they're all satisfied.  Your answer is therefore correct.

I think that If I didn't make that distinction between C and C' my system of equations wouldn't work. I needed to make difference between moves from D to C (that should not finish the chain) and from B to C (that should finish the chain).

If I make $p_C = p_{C'} = 0$ in my system of equations, I get $p_A = 4$ which is, as you say, wrong.

In your system of equations, putting $\ p_{C'}\ $ will give you $\ p_C=8\ ,$ so you can't put $\ p_C=0\ $ without introducing a contradiction, and you can then obtain any value whatsoever for any of the variables.  However, I do now understand your definition of $\ C'\ ,$ and believe your method of solution is fine.

Just to remind us that we're looking for an expected value rather than a probability, I'll use variables $e_A$, $e_B$, etc. instead of $p_A$, $p_B$, etc.
The ${}+1$ for each step is a relatively standard practice.
I assume that the final move from $B$ to $C$ is included in the "number of the move",
that is, if we had started on $B$ instead of $A$ and happened (by chance) to move to $C$ and not $A$, the "number of the move" on which the pawn moved from $B$ to $C$ would be $1$. This fits your formulation, where $e_{C'}=0$, indicating that we're counting the total number of moves to arrive at $C'$ (that is to say, to arrive at $C$ where the previous location was $B$).
You could simplify the problem a little in advance by using symmetry to merge node $C$ into $A$ (also using the fact that you treat $C$ distinctly from $C'$).
That is, before the final move, you are always either at $B$, one move away from $B$, or two moves away from $B$, and as far as the expected number of steps to get to $B$ is concerned, all that matters is how far you are.
In particular, $e_A = e_C$.
But we can also see this immediately from the first and third equations in your system,
which have exactly the same thing on the right hand side,
and eliminate $e_C$ that way.
I worked out the problem mentally in two stages: first stage getting from $A$ to $B$, which takes an expected $3$ steps, and then getting from $B$ to $C$ along the edge that connects them, which takes an expected $5$ steps.
(The reason the second stage takes longer than the first is that the first stage is allowed to arrive at $B$ from either direction.)
